# Openlayers 4 getting wrong pixel on mouse click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using ImageStatic with open layers.I am passing the below extent to the projection

```
this.extent = [0, 0, 2800, 1280];
```

Also i am using the below code get the pixel on map click

```
this.map.on('click', function (evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
```

But the x and y co ordinates value when I click on the map is not correct compared to the original x,y position

Am i missing anything?
[fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/3hr5gpw8/28/)

Comment: Coordinates seems ok to me... why you say that they are incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the code i found a that default coordinates of projection starts from BOTTOM LEFT corner (Y is UPWARD)

I fixed this with axisOrientation property of openlayers

Comment: Hey, I had the same issue, whitch axis orientation you put to fix this?